# How to check if email already exists in DB - JPA, Java, JBoss

Tags: java, jpa, jboss

I am trying to check if the email the user enters already exists in the db.
I have to methods (register and update) and one helper method in my UserBean.java:

```
    public String register() {
        if (emailAlreadyExists(this.user.getEmail())) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage("This e-Mail is already in use."));
        } else {
            this.conversation.end();
            try {
                if (this.id == null) {
                    this.entityManager.persist(this.user);
                    return "thanks.xhtml";
                } else {
                    this.entityManager.merge(this.user);
                    return "thanks.xhtml";
                }
            } catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
                Throwable t = e.getCause();
                while ((t != null)
                        && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
                if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                            new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String update() {
            if (emailAlreadyExists(this.user.getEmail())) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage("This e-Mail is already in use."));
            } else {
                this.conversation.end();
                try {
                    if (this.id == null) {
                        this.entityManager.persist(this.user);
                        return "search?faces-redirect=true";
                    } else {
                        this.entityManager.merge(this.user);
                        return "view?faces-redirect=true&id=" + this.user.getId();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                            new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

public boolean emailAlreadyExists(String emailAddr) {
        long counter = 0;
        counter = (Long) this.entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT COUNT(u.email) FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
                .setParameter("email", emailAddr).getSingleResult();
        if (counter > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I don't know why but this code works perfect for the register method (whenever I enter an existing email address), but not for the update method, although they are very similar.
Every time when I perform an user update, these SQL statements are performed in the following order (should be in reverse order):

```
22:44:20,865 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: update User set  country=?, email=?, firstName=?, lastName=?, password=?, phone=?, postalCode=? where id=?
22:44:20,875 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select count(user0_.email) as col_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.email=? limit ?
```

I already debugged the code and recognised that the update statement is executed on that line:

```
counter = (Long) this.entityManager
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT COUNT(u.email) FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
            .setParameter("email", emailAddr).getSingleResult();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the result of an update in the database (not the queries logged)? What happens when the email exists/doesn't exists?

Comment: Well, when the email exists I get this: 
`23:04:44,067 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Project_new].[FacesServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'alex@alex.at1' for key 'email'`.
I really don't understand the execution order AND even if I remove the whole code in the else, the update will be performed. Why? Is this something like an automatic entity update technique?

Comment: how about refreshing the user instance before validating the email existence? It seems to me that the user instance is in a stale state.

Comment: also, are you using containter managed transactions?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "refreshing" the user instance?

Comment: entityManager.refresh(user)

Comment: Could you try to just run the "emailAlreadyExists" method? what's the JPA log?

Comment: ok, let us know the result after the refresh.

Comment: Well, refreshing the user instance before validation the email didn't work. This is a really weird case, I never had that before. I don't even know how this can happen...

Comment: hmm...did you notice an extra query on the logs for refreshing the entity?

Comment: also, you should reassign the user entity with the result of every merge call.

Comment: Ok, after a Full Publish, I recognised that with refreshing the instance no update will be executed (which is good). However, I am not able to update the user with a non existing email. So I think there is a bug in my email validation method.

Comment: Don't fear. It's just a stale state.

Comment: please, just reassingn the user with the result of the merge operation. then when you validate again the email, the entity will not be in a stale state.

Comment: Is this what you mean: `this.user = this.entityManager.merge(this.user);`? Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55533/discussion-between-ra2085-and-user3475602).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a stale entity resulting of a transaction nightmate between JPA and your session bean. You've got to change your User entity lifecycle and make appropriate changes on your JPA transaction management.